# `Bazel run` won't find static file dependency in bazel-bin when running nodejs_image

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

I am trying to get a rules docker `nodejs_image` to run using bazel.

My command is

`bazel run :image.binary`

Here is my rule:

```
load("@npm//@bazel/typescript:index.bzl", "ts_project")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")

ts_project(
    name = "typescript_build",
    srcs = glob([
        "src/**/*",
    ]),
    allow_js = True,
    out_dir = "build",
    deps = ["@npm//:node_modules"],
)

nodejs_image(
    name = "image",
    data = [
        ":package.json",
        ":typescript_build",
        "@npm//:node_modules",
    ],
    entry_point = "build/app.js",
)
```

Basically, I need the `package.json` file because it includes some important configuration information when Node executes. If I call `bazel build :image` and then grab/run that image, everything works fine. But if I call `bazel run :image` it will basically work except that it can't find the `package.json`.

When I check the `bazel-bin/` folder, I've noticed that the `package.json` isn't included, but the built typescript and node_modules are. I'm guessing because I'm not running any prior rules on the package.json, it doesn't get added to the bin, but I really don't know how to work around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically, it seems that if you just use a rule like `copy_to_bin` or `js_library`, I think their purpose is to help put static files into your bazel-bin.

https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/Built-ins.html#copy_to_bin

```
ts_project(
    name = "typescript_build",
    srcs = glob([
        "src/**/*",
    ]),
    allow_js = True,
    out_dir = "build",
    deps = ["@npm//:node_modules"],
)

js_library(
    name = "library",
    srcs = ["package.json"],
    deps = [":typescript_build"],
)

nodejs_image(
    name = "image",
    data = [
        ":library",
        "@npm//:node_modules",
    ],
    entry_point = "build/app.js",
)
```